# PYTHON: Translation - Instant message abbreviation --> text?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In class we developed the IM translation program which takes an IM message 
consisting of acronyms and converts them full text. We used a dictionary which was created 
from a file called abbreviations.txt. You are required to extend the code to account for the 
following two additional requirements 1) take care punctuations and 2) if acronym is not in 
the dictionary, then keep it as it is in the translated message. 
- Use "abbreviations.txt" as the dictionary file name. Don't ask user the file name. 
- Punctuation mark only appears at the end of a word. There must be a blank between a 
punctuation mark and the next word. The punctuation marks you need to handle are: ",", 
".", "?", and "!".

abbreviations.txt =

y:why

r:are

u:you

l8:late

lol:laught out loud

BRB:Be right back

Here is my code so far :

```
# diimenhanced.py
#

def main():
    infile = open("abbreviations.txt", "r")
    d = {}
    w = []
    for line in infile:
        temp = line.split(":")
        d[temp[0]]=temp[1].rstrip()
        w.append(temp[0])
    infile.close()
    im = input("Please input the instant message:   ")
    tim = ""
    templist = im.split()

    for i in templist:
        if i[-1] in w:
            tim = tim + ' ' + d[i]
        else:
            word = i[0:-1]
            if word in w:
                tim = tim + ' ' + d[word] + i[-1]
            else:
                tim = tim + i

    print(tim)

main()
```

I've been trying to get it to work but it keeps on spitting out the same IM unless i put a period at the end. ex: BRB. ---> Be right back. and ex: BRB ---> BRB
:/ due Friday tomorrow, really need help! THANK YOU! and please im only in introductory python so if you could refrain from using BUILT-IN functions or complicated methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to split it into a list and make substitution there

```
def main():
    infile = open("abbreviations.txt", "r")
    d = {}
    w = []
    for line in infile:
        temp = line.split(":")
        d[temp[0]]=temp[1].rstrip()
        # For easy punctuation marks manage add these rules
        d[temp[0]+"?"] = temp[1].rstrip()+"?"
        d[temp[0]+"!"] = temp[1].rstrip()+"!"
        d[temp[0]+","] = temp[1].rstrip()+","
        d[temp[0]+"."] = temp[1].rstrip()+"."
        w.append(temp[0])
    infile.close()
    im = input("Please input the instant message:   ")
    im = im.split() # Split with space as separator
    res = "" # String to store the result
    for i in im: #Iterate over words
        if i in d: # If the word is in our dic
            res += d[i] # Add the substitution to result
        else: # If no substitution needed
            res += i  # Add original word
        res += " " # Add a space after each word

    res = res.strip() # Delete extra spaces at the end
    print(im)
    print(res)


main()
```

Comment: This actually worked a little better than my code, but when i tried it, replaced in the loop every letter.                               ex: input: lol. y r u l8 for class?                                 output: layought oyout loyoud. why are you late foare class?

Comment: I updated my answer with a better approach, try it out

Comment: Ohhh i see thanks Ruben! i almost had something like this but kinda got stuck with the strip. I tried it just now. it works for the most part but when theres a punctuation at the end it seems to not translate it.

Comment: The easy way to solve it, having just 4 punctuation marks, is add too your dictionary something like, for example, for `d[y] = why`, add also `d[y+"?"] = why+"?"`, `d[y+"!"] = why+"!"`, `d[y+","] = why+","`, `d[y+"."] = why+"."`

Comment: thank you so much, i was asking my TA and he said something about a dictionary with the punctuation marks. it works. im so stupid lol